# MySQL: Fill column with value from another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables **Branch***(id, name)* and **Subjects***(id, name, branchId, url)*.
The `url` in **Subjects** table is a *stored generated column* in the form of `"/branchName/subjectName"`. For example: `"/cse/compiler_design/"`.
There are only 6 records in **Branch** Table and it is already created.

How can i get the `branchName` for `url` from the `branchId` at the time of insertion of record as I don't want to update the column afterwards.

I am trying to create such schema in laravel with no success. This is my code:

```
Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('branchId')->unsigned();
    $branchName = DB::table('branch')->where('id', '=', 'branchId')->value('name');
    $table->string('url')->storedAs(' "/" + "' . $branchName . '" + "/" + name ');
});
```

Comment: You're mixing Laravel and MySQL logic, it's not going to work like that.  $branchName is going to be determined when you migrate the table, not when you insert data.  Personally, I would handle the url in the model.

Comment: @Devon I was just trying and it was no success. Suggest me a better way :)

Comment: Use an Eloquent mutator on the url field or just add a method getFullUrl() on the model.

Comment: ...Or create `branch` relationship (`belongsTo`) on the model and then access it with `$subjct->branch->name`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this just with MySQL?